# How Do I Get Diagnostic Logging On Windows 10 Boot?

Tags: windows-10, boot

After resizing and moving partitions I am unable to fully boot Windows.

It boots but then I get stuck on a black screen with a mouse pointer.

I tried `Ctrl-Alt-Del` and `Win+E` to bring up the task manager or start a new shell with Windows Explorer but it had no effect.

`Win+Ctrl+Shift+B` to reload the display driver didn't have an effect either.

The same thing occurs in Safe Mode and automatic repair doesn't fix it.

"A black screen with mouse pointer" doesn't give much to go on to work out what is broken.

How do I enable diagnostic logging during the boot process so that I have a file to inspect for errors?

Comment: See if this helps>>>https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-boot-log-windows-10

Comment: I tried that too. Unfortunately it just tells me which drivers have been loaded. It doesn't give me any info about what errors have occurred to work out why the login screen is not showing.

Comment: Try this one>>>https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/support-software/Diagnostic-Startup-Windows-10-1389/

Comment: Microsoft has a guide for debugging a stalled system. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-a-stalled-system It requires the use of a kernel debugger though so it's pretty advanced, but if you're able to do it, it will give you the answers you're looking for.